# Bootstrap Container-fluid adding padding on the right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to design a web page everything works but container-fluid is adding extra padding on the right. [image]

As you can see in the picture there's a gap right after the navigation bar ends.

This is my **index.html** :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Custom Stylesheets and Scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css"> </head>

<body>
    <!-- navigation bar -->
    <div class="container-fluid navigation-bar-container  text-center" >
        <div class="navigation-bar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="navigation-item">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn">Home</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content"> 
                                                        <a href="#">Login</a> 
                            <a href="#">Register</a> 

                            <a href="#">Van Boening Sets World Record</a> 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="navigation-item">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn">Tour Info</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="#">How it Works</a> <a href="#">Games Played</a> <a href="#">How to get your room playing</a> <a href="#">Become an event coordinator</a> <a href="#">Mission and Goals</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="logo"> <img src="resources/images/Logos/Logo%20Vertical%20Transparent.png" class="img-responsive center-block"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="navigation-item">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn">Events</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="#">Schedule</a> <a href="#">Results</a> <a href="#">Locations</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="navigation-item">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn">Contact</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my **app.css:**

```
body{
   font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.navigation-bar{
 background-color: black;
  height: 65px;
  padding-top: 10px;


}

.navigation-bar-container{
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;

}


.navigation-item{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block
}

.dropdown-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color:#8CFB76;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1E392A;
    min-width: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #cccccc;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #234331;
    color: #e6e6e6;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

This is my **index.css** :

```
  body{
 background-color: #1a1a1a;

}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can fix this?

**Edit:**

After Changing the code like ZenSystem suggested:

[image]

Comment: You also need to move your jquery.min.js script above bootstrap.min.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In Bootstrap, `.row` should be the immediate child of
  `.container-fluid`
- The padding on `.navigation-bar-container` is breaking the normal offset container provides for the `.row`

Change it to this..

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <div class="navigation-bar row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                   <div class="navigation-item">
                    ...
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/NPtXsxCSxX

Comment: Thankyou!! but the horizontall scroll is still there should I reduce some width or something?

Comment: The horizontal scroll shouldn't be there anymore. It's not in the Codeply.

Comment: I added the picture please check it out

Comment: It would only still be there is there is padding on the container. Are you sure you removed the `navigation-bar-container` class?

Comment: oops I just did ThankYou